# Convert three arrays into a nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6, lodash

I want to create a nested object, like this

```
var obj; 
obj = [
    {
        "a": {
            "A" : "aA",
            "B" : "aB",
            "C" : "aC"
        }

    },
    {
        "b": {
            "A" : "bA",
            "B" : "bB",
            "C" : "bC"
        }

    },
    {
        "c": {
            "A" : "cA",
            "B" : "cB",
            "C" : "cC"
        }

    },      
]
```

from three arrays like this

```
var arr1 = ["a","b","c"]
var arr2 = ["A","B","C"]
var arr3 = [["aA","aB","aC"],["bA","bB","bC"], ["cA","cB","cC"]]
```

Is there an easy way using lodash or es6? I am essentially generating `arr3` from `arr1` and `arr2` using another function. But that is not of much relevance here, yet if I were to create such multiple arrays of data and i want to generate JSON like objects by combining the arrays, what is a convenient approach? Is there any documentation regarding creating multi-level nested objects from several arrays, maybe more than 3 arrays?

My effort ...

```
arr1.forEach((item)=>{
    arr2.forEach((prop)=>{
        obj[item] = {}
        obj[item][prop] =  prop
    })
})
```

Comment: Now we know what you want, but we've no clue, what you have done to get your problem solved.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because question does not show any sign of effort. This is a requirement and not a problem statement.

Comment: @Rajesh: Usually, we use "Too broad" for that reason.

Comment: We discourage posts that simply state a problem out of context, and expect the community to solve it. Assuming you tried to solve it yourself and got stuck, it may be helpful if you wrote your thoughts and what you could not figure out. It will definitely draw more answers to your post. Until then, the question will be voted to be closed / downvoted.

Comment: I'm not asking the exact solution, all I'm asking is any source where I can figure out how to do it on my own. Please read the question again. The problem statement is what is the approach to solve a complex problem like this. Please un-downvote if you are convinced. Thank you

Comment: @Cerbrus I use custom message because if user has tried something but has forgotten to add it, he/she can add it. Objective here is to notify that question will be closed due to missing information. *Too broad* does not inform OP until the post is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
  var arr1 = ["a","b","c"];
  var arr2 = ["A","B","C"];
  var arr3 = [["aA","aB","aC"],["bA","bB","bC"], ["cA","cB","cC"]];
  var obj=[]; //initializing empty obj array
  for (i=0;i<arr1.length;i++){ // loop for creating outer objects
  var insideObj = {}, sampleObj={};
  for (j=0;j<arr2.length;j++) // loop for creating inner objects
    insideObj[arr2[j]]=arr3[i][j]; // creating inner objects like {"A":"cA","B":"cB","C":"cC"}
  sampleObj[arr1[i]]= insideObj; // assigning inner object as value of outer object
  obj.push(sampleObj); // pushing outer object to my obj array
}
```